# vscode remote debugging console always prints "Cannot evaluate expression on the specified stack frame."

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

While debugging in vscode there appears to be a gdb console at the bottom. Currently I'm remotely connecting to `gdbserver` and able to pause on a breakpoint. I'd like to be able to type gdb commands into the console. The problem is no matter what I type, such as `info sharedlibrary`, it prints the following:

```
info sharedlibrary
Cannot evaluate expression on the specified stack frame.
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct interface with gdb. To get commands to go through you need to type `-exec`. The error message is just painfully confusing.

```
-exec info sharedlibrary
...
```

In fact the following can be found in the same console, it's just easy to miss when there's a pile of other output:

```
Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example "-exec info registers" will list registers in use (when GDB is the debugger)
```